# Need help trimming spaces out of column

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to figure out how to loop through the first column of my worksheet and take out the spaces so I can use VLOOKUP. Not sure how to do it in VBA. Here is what I have:

I can't figure out why it does not go onto the next sheet now? I can't just cycle through all of the sheets since they are different.

```
Sub trima()
Dim x As Integer
Dim numrows As Long


      numrows = Range("A1",Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

      Range("A1").Select

      For x = 1 To numrows
         Application.WorksheetFunction.trim (ActiveCell)
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
      Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Uh oh, never post edits like that. Please restore the post with your original code and then post your additional and/or now working code below instead. Otherwise, other people won't benefit as much from reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Trim` function does not work like that.

Instead, try something like:

```
Sub trima()

      Dim numrows As Long
      Dim vItem as Variant
      Dim i As Long

      numrows = Range("A1",Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      With ActiveSheet
         For i = 1 To numrows
            vItem = .Range("A" & i)
            If vItem <> vbNullString then .Range("A" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(vItem)
         Next
      End With

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The following code will loop through ALL worksheets in the Workbook and perform the same trim on values in Column A:

```
Sub trimA()

      Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
      Dim i As Long, numrows As Long
      Dim vItem As Variant

      Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      For Each ws In Worksheets

        With ws

           numrows = .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count

           For i = 1 To numrows
              vItem = .Range("A" & i)
              If vItem <> vbNullString Then .Range("A" & i) = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(vItem)
           Next i

        End With

      Next

      Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks this is working. one problem I am having, is now I am trying to go onto the next worksheet. 

worksheets("next name").select

and essentially running the same code again. Except for on the second sheet it is not working. Any idea why? @miqi180

Comment: Please try the edited code above, I forgot to put "Application.WorksheetFunction" before "Trim" in the loop. Credits to pnuts for spotting this. If it still doesn't work, then please post your additional code.

Comment: Posted the new code above. How to I make it go to the next sheet? works on the first sheet, but not sheet2

Comment: Added additional tried and tested code which loops through all worksheets in the workbook. If you only need to do this with specific sheets, then you need to activate them one by one, and the run the original code on them, e.g. by creating an additional macro that activates the sheet in question and then calls the trima sub, or by adding code in the loop which tests the sheetname against your criteria. If this works for you, then please accept the answer. Thx

Comment: You're answer was great. I think there is something going on on my end with the second sheet. Even the =trim() function is not working on it. So i guess there is some other character that vbNullString isn't catching?

Comment: Thx. Please be more specific. How is it not working? Does the program crash, or does nothing appear to happen on that sheet when you run the code? Have you checked that the cells on the second sheet are formatted correctly?

Comment: Right so i just tested in normal excel to see why the program wasn't triming the cells. =trim did nothing, =clean did. SO there is some non-printable chars in the cell. So...Yeah Let me attempt that in VBA

Comment: Boom. Just added it onto your code and got it. Thank you! Sorry im such a donk.

Comment: Good job. I presume you replaced vItem =.Range("A" & i) with vItem = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(.Range("A" & i)). That works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go:

```
Sub TrimA()
    Dim v
    v = [transpose(transpose(trim(a1:index(a:a,match("",a:a,-1)))))]
    [a1].Resize(UBound(v)) = v
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

If you want to update multiple sheets, you can utilize the above like so:

```
Sub DoTrims()
    Sheet1.Activate: TrimA
    Sheet2.Activate: TrimA
    'etc.
End If
```

Comment: @scarebear Please see the update to my answer. It shows how to do the trimming for multiple sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) should quickly clear all cells containing leading/trailing spaces.

This procedure can quickly convert *text-that-look-like-numbers* to true numbers as well.

```
Dim c As Long
With Range("A1").CurrentRegion  `<~~ set to the desired range of one or more columns
    For c = 1 To .Columns.Count
        .Columns(c).TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns(c), _
            DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 1)
    Next c
End With
```

If the cells actually contain non-standard spacing like the non-breaking space (common on data copied from a web page) then other [Range.Replace method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) should be added.